# Finding percentile of a column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find the 80th percentile of a column in SQL Server Management Studio using the `Percentile_DISC(0.8)` function but it wants me to partition by.  Is there any way I can use this function to find the percentile of the whole column and not partitioning? I just want one single value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is more than one type of percentile available.  Which one do you want?

Comment: @DanBracuk  I'm not sure what you mean, unless you mean discrete or continuous and I have discrete in my question above.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - try `Percentile_DISC(0.8) within group (order by ...) over ()`